# Floating point exception with 'static inline std::unordered_map<...>' in ICC

Tags: c++, c++17, inline, unordered-map, icc

The following code compiles and runs properly with GCC 8.2.0 (using `-std=c++17`). It also compiles with Intel's ICC 19.0.1.144, but throws a 'Floating point exception' when trying to access 'map' in the constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

struct A {
    static inline std::unordered_map<int, int> map;
    A(){
        map[1] = 2;
    }
};

int main(){
    A a;
}
```

A similar code with a primitive or 'std::vector' in place of 'std::unordered_map' appears to work.

Is this a problem with the Intel compiler? It should support inline variables, according to [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/c17-features-supported-by-intel-c-compiler).

Comment: Question was posted here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/comment/1933601#comment-1933601. Appears to be an issue with the compiler.